# Kali `startx` Error GUI not showing

Tags: raspberry-pi, kali-linux

I have a RPI3 and has a kali image that was working until one day.

The last thing I remember I did was that I installed `gparted` and expanded the partition to full but the part I expanded was highlighted as unallocated and after that day my kali is showing booting errors and is not showing the GUI system when `startx` is written.

Thanks in advance.

> **Note:** My pi-top has different problems and one of them is that does not turn on when unplugged from electricity.

Comment: Please don't cross-post the [same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459002/kali-startx-error-gui-not-showing) on multiple sites. Related: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) - TL;DR: No.

Comment: I think this is the right place for this kind of posts

Comment: Sure, it's on-topic here. And I see you deleted your post on [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) now. Thank you.

Comment: @n8te will it take time to start a bounty?

Comment: Yes, it takes two days before a bounty can be started on a question. For further reading: [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://superuser.com/help/bounty). You also need at least 75 reputation before you unlock the privilege to be able to start a bounty.

Comment: It's probably easier to just create a new kali image on your sd card and start from scratch, no?

Comment: @n8te Yes I think but there is one more problem left expanding the partition. I need to expand the partition in order to download updates, Kali tools, etc.. But when I resize my partition it highlights the new resized partition as un-allocated can this be solved?Thanks

Comment: @n8te Can I start a bounty for this user?

Comment: @YoussofHammoud - You are not able to start a bounty until the question has been up for two days. At that point you will be able to.

Comment: @n8te Ok thanks now I remember why the "Start a Bounty" link is not showing.